como puedo reiniciar todos los componentes de mi aplicación flet?
Alguien sabe como puedo hacer para reiniciar todos los componentes de una aplicación flet?
la cosa es que tengo un menu configuración en donde se puede elegir un idioma, lo que quiero es que al tocar el idioma, la aplicación se reinicie, alguien sabe como?
  def change_language(lang):
    #Cerrar el menú de opciones
    close_dlg()
    #Definir el lenguaje de la aplicación al nuevo
    self.language = lang
    #cargar las preferencias del usuario
    current_preferences = load_preferences()
    #editar el idioma al nuevo
    current_preferences["language"] = lang
    #guardar las preferencias editadas
    edit_preferences(current_preferences)
    #y acá es donde debería de reiniciarse la app
    self.page.update()

